Green Function equation
I have a doubt on how to compute the green function $G$ of an operator $O$. By definition the green function of an operator $O$ is,
$$\int dx_2 O(x_1,x_2)G(x_2,x_3)=\delta(x_1-x_3)$$
my operator is,
$$O(x_1,x_2) = (i\partial_{x_1}-\omega_0-t\delta(x_1))\delta(x_1-x_2)$$
usually when my operator is
$$O(x_1,x_2) = (i\partial_{x_1}-\omega_0)\delta(x_1-x_2)$$
I can easily invert it by means of fourier transform and I get,
$$G(x_2-x_3)=\int \frac{dk}{2\pi} \frac{e^{-ik(x_2-x_3)}}{k-\omega - i\eta}$$ with $\eta \rightarrow 0$, but now with the additional term $-t\delta(x_1)$ I found it more complicated and I have problems on how to start. Can someone give me an hint?

How exactly have you found it more complicated?

What have you attempted so far?

I tried to write the fourier transform of G to see if I can simplify the problem but nothing
